How to count traffic of virtual machine?
I have an hypervisor with Ubuntu Server 18.04. There are some virtual machines which are powered by VirtualBox. I've setup iptables and iproute2 in order Internet on VMs could work via "Host-Only Adapter"
vboxnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.11.11.11  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 72648  bytes 3266388 (3.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vboxnet1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.11.11.11  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vboxnet2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.11.11.11  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 92219  bytes 10396788 (10.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

I even can sniff VM's traffic
root@hypervisor:~# tcpdump -n -i vboxnet0 port 8642
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on vboxnet0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:31:43.676271 IP 188.17.218.126.1971 > 78.29.xx.xx.8642: Flags [P.], seq 3363265001:3363265037, ack 1117219726, win 1026, length 36
12:31:43.676407 IP 78.29.xx.xx.8642 > 188.17.218.126.1971: Flags [.], ack 36, win 501, length 0
12:31:48.673973 IP 188.17.218.126.1971 > 78.29.xx.xx.8642: Flags [P.], seq 36:72, ack 1, win 1026, length 36
12:31:48.674050 IP 78.29.xx.xx.8642 > 188.17.218.126.1971: Flags [.], ack 72, win 501, length 0
12:31:53.675466 IP 188.17.218.126.1971 > 78.29.xx.xx.8642: Flags [P.], seq 72:108, ack 1, win 1026, length 36
12:31:53.675547 IP 78.29.xx.xx.8642 > 188.17.218.126.1971: Flags [.], ack 108, win 501, length 0
^C
6 packets captured
6 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

78.29.xx.xx is VM
However, ifconfig of hypervisor doesn't count traffic if it's related to VM
Is there any package that could count all traffic?

SNMP is the usual go-to option for measuring network traffic stats.
